# Evolution in time of the position for a specific point

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations

**Simple case**

Let $f:\Bbb R \times \Bbb R_+  \to \Bbb C$ be a solution of

$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}=i\dfrac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x^2}$$

The initial condition for $t=0$ can be considered a generic function $g(x)$.

Consider that that there is at least one point $x_0$ so that $\dfrac{d ^2 g}{d x^2}(x_0)=0$.

Say $X_0(t)$ has the property that 
$$
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x^2}(X_0(t),t)=0\\[2ex]
X_0(0) = x_0
\end{cases}
$$

Is there a way to calculate $X_0(t)$ or is there a method (name) that can be used to calculate it?

**Real case**

Consider the same function $f$ with $g(x)$ as initial condition. The condition for $X_0(t)$ applies only on one of the following: $\rm{Re}(f)$, $\rm{Im}(f)$ or $|f|$. The question is the same, find $X_0(t)$ or what is the name of the method used to do so, if it exists.